# How to change the inner radius color of Victory Pie Chart in React Native?

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

[image of circle filled with background colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbzVo.png)
How to change the color of inner radius of Victory Pie Chart in React Native?

Just want to change the inner radius circle from background color to white

My current Code

```
<Block marginVertical={sizes.sm} align="center">
                  <VictoryPie
                    style={{labels: {display: 'none'}}}
                    height={350}
                    width={350}
                    innerRadius={120}
                    colorScale={[colors.primary, colors.gray]}
                    animate={{
                      duration: 2000,
                    }}
                    data={[
                      {x: 'Holding', y: 90000},
                      {x: 'Cash', y: 10000},
                    ]}
                  />

                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: 'absolute',
                      top: '46%',
                      width: '100%',
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      onPress={() =>
                        showBalance
                          ? setShowBalance(false)
                          : setShowBalance(true)
                      }
                      h3
                      center>
                      100,000
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </Block>
```

NOTE: Also showing Text inside the pie chart using position absolute